# Running a shell script in a Django app deployed using Apache + mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

In my Django application, I want to upload and execute a bash script. Uploading is OK, but the script is not executing. I am uploading the file in /home/ubuntu0/example/tmp. I already changed the owner of this
directory to web-data, before running the Django app, so that uploading will be surely successful. Like this:

```
sudo chown -R web-data:web-data /home/ubuntu0/exampl/tmp
```

I started the Django app and as mentioned, uploading is successful. However, the permission of the uploaded bash script is read-only.That's why before calling:

```
os.system(<uploaded_bash_script_filename>)
```

in the uploadAndExecute functiion of the apps' views.py, I inserted:

```
os.chmod(<uploaded_bash_script_filename>, 777)
```

first. However, the script did not execute, and when I checked the permission of the uploaded bash script, it's still read only. I did try using subprocess module to change permission and execute the script:

```
subprocess.call(['sudo', 'chmod', '777', <uploaded_bash_script_filename>])
subprocess.call(['sudo', <uploaded_bash_script_filename>])
```

But on the chmod part, I am having a 'No such file or directory' error. It seems that the subprocess module can't see the uploaded bash script, though it's really existing (by browsing/ ls).

How will I resolve this? Any ideas are greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What user and group does Django run via your webserver? My bet is SELinux is preventing this from happening, since this is beyond a huge security issue, and you should never do what you're trying to do anyway. Try disabling SELinux then trying again, or look in /var/log/secure to see if it's being prevented. Also, the call to sudo from python's subprocess.call is running as the user:group that your webserver runs as, and it's likely that user has no permission to execute the file in question.